# Simple way to order grep's result by time (reverse)?

Tags: grep, ksh, aix

I often have to look for specific strings in a big set of log files with **[grep](/questions/tagged/grep)**. And I get lots of results, on what I must scroll a lot.

Today, the results of `grep` list the results in alphabetical order. I would like to have my grep results *reversed ordered by time*, like a *`ls -ltr`* would do.

I know I could take the result of `ls -ltr` and grep file by file. I do it like this:

```
 ls -ltr ${my_log_dir}\* | awk '{print $9}' |xargs grep ${my_pattern}
```

But I wonder: Is there a simpler way?

PS: I'm using `ksh` on `AIX`.

Comment: @fedorqui, added my actual ***complex*** way of doing it. Ok it is already simple

Comment: Uhms, this is hard. Parsing ls is not a good idea. However, the alternatives that come to my mind are things like using `find` to print the datetime, then perform the `grep` and remove the datetime part. A bit ugly.

Comment: @fedorqui, if I just use `ls -tr`, I don't need parsing, but does the `| xargs` get all and ordered results?

Comment: You do parse when you use `awk '{print $9}'`. And yup, this should work. Use `grep -H` to get the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found (thanks to Fedorqui) was to simply use `ls -tr`. It assumes the results are passed in the right order through the `|` to  `xargs` allowing then to do the `grep`.

My misconception was that since when I us `ls`, the results arrive not as a single column list but as a multiple column list, it couldn't work as an input for `xargs`.

Here is the simplest solution to date, since it avoids any `awk` parsing:

```
ls -tr ${my_log_dir}\* | xargs grep ${my_pattern}
```

I checked, and every result of the `ls -t` are passed to  `xargs` even though they look not as I expected they would enter easily in it:

```
srv:/papi/tata $ ls -t
addl      ieet      rrri     
ooij      lllr      sss      
srv:/papi/tata $ ls -t |xargs -I{} echo {}
addl 
ieet  
rrri     
ooij  
lllr  
sss
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work too use `find` command:-

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 stat -c %y\ %n | sort -r | awk '{print $4}' | sed "s|^\./||"
```

- `-print0` in find to preserve files having special characters(whitespaces, tabs)
- Print file status (`stat` with `%y` (Time of last modification) and `%n` (%n     File name) with output having new-separated (`-c`)
- Reverse sort the output from previous command. (`-r` for reverse)
- `awk '{print $4}'` printing only the file-name (can be optimized as needed)
- Removing the leading `./` from the file-names.

Comment: HI Inian, Thanks for your help. It says me: *find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option.*. What shell / OS are you on? Me it's: ksh / AIX

Comment: Works fine on `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`. assuming your files don't have special characters or whitespaces on them, you can also try `find -type f -print | xargs -r stat -c %y\ %n | sort -r | awk '{print $4}' | sed "s|^\./||"` , which is basically removing the `-print0` flag

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot check it here on my computer.